# Apropos on Arch returns "Nothing Appropriate," no makewhatis command

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, man

I've been having a problem with apropos on both my Arch linux install and my ArchBang install.

When I run the `apropos` or the `whatis` command, it returns "nothing appropriate" for anything I enter, including even things like 'man' and 'ls'.

Other sources have suggested running the `makewhatis` command, but both my systems can't find that command. I looked in the /usr/sbin directory, and there's no makewhatis binary located there.

I reinstalled the entire man package, but that made no other changes.

Could this possibly not be present in the packages stored in the arch RPMs?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to run [mandb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Man_Page#Searching_manuals) as root and run it again, every time you've installed new manpages.

Comment: In KDE neon, which is an Ubuntu variant, ``sudo systemctl enable --now man-db.service`` worked.